# Show that if $\left|T\left(x\right)-T\left(y\right)\right|\geq c\left|x-y\right|$ then $v\left(T\left(E\right)\right)\geq c^{n}v\left(E\right)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, diffeomorphism

Let $c>0$ be a real positive number and let $T\colon\mathbb{R}^{n}\to\mathbb{R}^{n}$
be a diffeomorphism such that $\left|T\left(x\right)-T\left(y\right)\right|\geq c\left|x-y\right|$.
I wish to show that for every Jordan Measurable set $E$ we have $v\left(T\left(E\right)\right)\geq c^{n}v\left(E\right)$.

In my attempt I realized that using change of variables we get
$$
v\left(T\left(E\right)\right)=\int_{T\left(E\right)}1=\int_{E}\left|J_{T}\left(x\right)\right|
$$
where $J_{T}$ is the Jacobian of $T$, and therefore it is sufficient to show
that for every $x\in E$ we have $\left|J_{T}\left(x\right)\right|\geq c^{n}$.
I couldn't see how to prove that so I was thinking about looking first
on the case where $c=1$, but also there I couldn't figure how to
do it. Any suggestions?

**EDIT:**

More I know is that for every $x,h\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$ we have $T\left(x+h\right)=T\left(x\right)+D_{T}\left(x\right)\left(h\right)+o\left(\left|h\right|\right)$
and therefore
$$
\begin{align*}
c\left|h\right| & \leq\left|T\left(x+h\right)-T\left(x\right)\right|=\left|D_{T}\left(x\right)\left(h\right)+o\left(\left|h\right|\right)\right|\leq\\
 & \leq\left|D_{T}\left(x\right)\left(h\right)\right|+\left|o\left(\left|h\right|\right)\right|\leq\left\Vert D_{T}\left(x\right)\right\Vert \left|h\right|+o\left(\left|h\right|\right)
\end{align*}
$$
so $c\leq\left\Vert D_{T}\left(x\right)\right\Vert +\frac{o\left(\left|h\right|\right)}{\left|h\right|}$
and when $h\to0$ we get $\left\Vert D_{T}\left(x\right)\right\Vert \geq c$

Answer (score 1):

$T(x+tv)=T(x)+dT_x(tv)+tO(t)$. We deduce that $\|{{\|T(x+tv)-T(x)\|}\over{\|tv\|}}=\|dT_x({v\over \|v\|})+O(t)\|\geq c$. This implies that $\|dT_x(v)\|\geq c\|v\|$.

Let $e$ be an eigenvalue of $dT_x$ associated to the eigenvector $u$ (I will eventually work with the complexification), we have:

$T(x+tv)=T(x)+dT_x(tv)+tO(t)=T(x)+etv+tO(t)$, we deduce that:

$\|{{\|T(x+tv)-T(x)\|}\over{\|tv\|}}=\|e({v\over \|v\|})+O(t)\|\geq c$.

Comment: How can I use that to prove what I need?

Comment: This implies that the norm of the eigenvalues of the Jacobian are superior to $c$.

Comment: How it implies that?